# How to extend a function without body in golang

Tags: inheritance, go, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to user the [ippy04/messengerbot](https://github.com/ippy04/messengerbot/) library to build a bot for the facebook messenger.

For receiving a new message the library uses a construct I can´t wrap my head around. The following function type is defined (but without body) in the relevant [library source file](https://github.com/ippy04/messengerbot/blob/master/webhook.go#L66):

```
type MessageReceivedHandler func(*MessengerBot, Event, MessageOpts, ReceivedMessage)
```

This type then [gets attached](https://github.com/ippy04/messengerbot/blob/master/messengerbot.go#L10) to the actual bot:

```
type MessengerBot struct {
    MessageReceived  MessageReceivedHandler
}
```

Later in the code [it gets called](https://github.com/ippy04/messengerbot/blob/master/webhook.go#L121-L123) like this:

```
if bot.MessageReceived != nil {
  go bot.MessageReceived(bot, entry.Event, message.MessageOpts, *message.Message)
}
```

Now it seems I need to extend `MessageReceivedHandler` with an actual body implementation in my own package. I tried a few thing.

Following another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800672/how-to-add-new-methods-to-an-existing-type-in-go) I did this:

```
import "github.com/ippy04/messengerbot"
type myMRH messengerbot.MessageReceivedHandler
func (mr myMRH) HRM() {
    log.Println("works!")
}
```

... but that code never gets called.

Also I tried to extend `bot.MessageReceived` like this (I´m using GinGonic)

```
router.POST("/webhook", func(c *gin.Context) {
    bot := messengerbot.NewMessengerBot(os.Getenv("FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"), os.Getenv("FB_MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN"))
    bot.Debug = true
    bot.MessageReceived = func(*MessengerBot, Event, MessageOpts, ReceivedMessage) {
        log.Println("works!")
    }
    bot.Handler(c.Writer, c.Request)
})
```

but then I have no idea where to get the necessary function variables from since they ar enot exposed by the library.

Any idea on how to implement that `MessageReceivedHandler`?

---

Based on the answer from @mykola here is the complete solution to my problem:

```
router.POST("/webhook", func(c *gin.Context) {
    bot := messengerbot.NewMessengerBot(os.Getenv("FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"), os.Getenv("FB_MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN"))
    bot.Debug = true
    bot.MessageReceived = func(bot *messengerbot.MessengerBot, evt messengerbot.Event, opts messengerbot.MessageOpts, msg messengerbot.ReceivedMessage) {
        log.Println(msg.Message.Text)
    }
    bot.Handler(c.Writer, c.Request)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that someone somewhere has declared a new type derived from `messengerbot.MessageReceivedHandler` doesn't and shouldn't have any effect on the bot library itself.

What you need is to set the handler of the bot either at the construction point, by instantiating it yourself, or later by doing

```
bot.MessageReceived = func(bot *MessengerBot, evt Event, opts MessageOpts, msg ReceivedMessage) {
  log.Println("works!", msg)
}
```

P.S. You might want to check the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) if you haven't yet, as you seem to miss some basic concepts of working with go.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tried that already but discovered that I don´t have access to the necessary variables to fill the function parameters. I´ll add that to my main question.
Did the tour of go of course but that was some time ago ;) think I´ll refresh. Actually I had a look into it yesterday to find a hint for my problem but couldn´t make out anything fitting the case. The chapter about interfaces didn´t seem to apply here.

Comment: the variables are supposed to be sent by the library to the callback. I've expanded the example to make it clear.

Comment: Got it. The only thing I had to add was to import the types from the library package. Thx!