# Is there a way to convert structs in different packages in Go using maps and interfaces?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, type-conversion

I want to convert some struct types between different packages and then operate on the structs that are in my package without using `if/else` or `switch` statements. Is that possible to do using just `maps` and `interfaces`? I have some ideas in place for how I can do this.

#### Package Other

```
type Update interface{}

type FirstUpdate struct {
    x int
    y int
}

type SecondUpdate struct {
    z string
}

// these methods return different implementations of Update structs
FirstRequestConverter(events []string, topic string) Update
SecondRequestConverter(events []string, topic string) Update
```

#### Package Mine

```
type ConversionFunction func([]string, string) other.Update

type FirstUpdateConverted other.FirstUpdate
type SecondUpdateConverted other.SecondUpdate

type ServiceCaller interface {
    // includes relevant methods
}    

topicsMap := map[string]ConversionFunction{
    "first_topic": other.FirstRequestConverter,
    "second_topic": other.SecondRequestConverter,
}

conversionFunction = topicsMap[topic]
// need to convert other package types to alias types
...
updateConverted.callService()
```

Here, my map from `string` to `ConversionFunction` lets me pick the conversion function I want to use at runtime. And if both `FirstUpdateConverted` and `SecondUpdateConverted` implement the `ServiceCaller` interface, I can choose how the converted structure is handled at runtime too.

In order to convert from `FirstUpdate` to `FirstUpdateConverted` (or any of the other alias types), however, I need to use a `switch` and convert manually.

Is there another way to do the struct conversion step?

Comment: Why are you renaming types from other packages within your package? That's usually not something you want to do.

Comment: I want to add additional methods to those types, and it seems that I can either use aliases or embedding. The alias within my package will not be exported.

Comment: Type "aliases" don't exist yet (coming in go1.9), and renaming a type creates an entirely new type with a new method set. You almost always want to use embedding to add to the method set.

Comment: Yup in this case I do want a new type with a new method set. I saw this page earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800672/how-to-add-new-methods-to-an-existing-type-in-go  . But I think I'm seeing that what I want to do isn't possible because of the static typing of Go (using reflect to convert interface to struct)

Comment: I have to agree that there is some design flaw here, but I can't say what specifically without more context. It seems like you may have painted yourself into a corner architecturally. This looks like a potential [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).