# Interface with methods that return itself

Tags: go, interface

Package `term`:

```
type Num interface {
    IsNeg()  bool
    Add(Num) Num
}

type Term struct {
    Coeff Num
    Var   string
}
```

External package `frac64`

```
type Frac64 struct {
    Numer uint64
    Denom uint64
    Neg   bool
}

func (a Frac64) Add(b Frac64) Frac64 { // Pretend this is implemented }
```

Package `client`

```
type Frac Frac64

func (f Frac) IsNeg()  bool   { return f.Neg }
func (f Frac) Add(v Num) Num  { // Call Frac64's Add here? }
```

How would I go about implementing `Add` for `Frac` so that it implements the `Num` interface?

### EDIT: Additional info

The external package `frac64` was just an example. I do not intend to use it.

The goal here (and I should have been clearer) is for my package to expose the struct `Term` that uses `Num` as one of its two properties. Now, I want users of my package to be able to use `big.Rat` or `Frac64` or `int64` or `rune` or whatever they want, as long as they implement the `Num` interface.

The problem I have is trying to implement the `Num` interface for a struct that already has functions with the same name as the functions in `Num`. This is where `Frac64` comes in. I could've also used `big.Rat` as an example, as it also has a function called `Add`.

I can't change the implementation of `Frac64` (or `big.Rat` for that matter), and I also can't extend it with an `Add` function as it already exists. That's why I tried to use `type Frac Frac64` (or `type Frac big.Rat`) and then trying to extend `Frac`.

I fail to implement `Num` for `Frac` though, because I'm not able to call `Frac64`'s `Add` from the `Frac`'s `Add` function.

Comment: `Plus` and `Term` are never referenced. It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Some code to show how you want this to work would help.

Comment: Are you reimplementing [`Rat` from the big package](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) as an exercise?

Comment: I should have written more information in the original post. I tried to create a minimal example that showcases my problem. The structs themselves could've been anything.

With Frac64 I tried to create a minimal example of an immutable struct with an Add function.

In the client I'm trying to implement the Num interface for Frac which is a typedef Frac64 that also has an Add function that doesn't match with Num's Add.

Comment: I basically want the people who use my package with the `Term` struct to be able to use any struct they see fit to be used as a coefficient as long as it implements Num.

Comment: An interface is incomplete, IMHO. How does catch a case if a parameter of Add method isn't Frac64? How you convert it? Or return an error? You should add a method to get both parts of a number or converting it for ex.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)...

```
type Frac struct {
    *Frac64
}
```

Now `Frac` can use `Frac64`'s methods, no need to rewrite them.

```
// `Frac.New(numer, denom, bool)` would remove this implementation leak.
foo := Frac{
    &Frac64 {
        Numer: 45,
        Denom: 99,
        Neg: false,
    },
}
fmt.Println(foo.IsNeg())
```

But there's a snag when we try to use `Add`.

```
// cannot use foo (type Frac) as type Frac64 in argument to foo.Frac64.Add
fmt.Println(foo.Add(foo))
```

Embedding only works for inheriting methods. When used as an argument it won't use the embedded reference for you, you'd have to do that explicitly.

The real problem is `func (a Frac64) Add(b Frac64) Frac64` does not satisfy the Num interface. If we fix that it works fine because `Frac` implements `Num`.

```
func (a Frac64) Add(b Num) Num {
    return Frac64{
        Numer: 12,
        Denom: 23,
        Neg: false,
    }
}
```

---

That works, but it's awkward to build a less specific type, `Frac`, from a more specific type, `Frac64`.

From here it becomes a bit more obvious that `Frac` is a `Num` with some extensions. `Frac` should be an interface extending `Num` and adding a numerator and denominator. `Frac64` becomes a type implementing `Frac`.

```
type Num interface {
    IsNeg()  bool
    Add(Num) Num
}

type Frac interface {
    Numer() uint
    Denom() uint
    Num
}

type Frac64 struct {
    numer uint64
    denom uint64
    neg bool
}

func (f Frac64) IsNeg() bool {
    return f.neg
}

func (f Frac64) Numer() uint {
    return uint(f.numer)
}

func (f Frac64) Denom() uint {
    return uint(f.denom)
}

func (a Frac64) Add(b Num) Num {
    // Just a placeholder to show it compiles.
    return Frac64{
        numer: 12,
        denom: 34,
        neg: false,
    }
}
```

This is fine for an exercise. In production, consider using [`big.Rat`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Rat).

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. I have added some additional information in my post. Both of your suggestions change `Frac64`'s `Add` function though, which I cannot do as it is in an external package.

Comment: I came over this though which seems to explain my problem quite clearly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43507669/2966323

I guess I need to use embedding as you say instead of an alias in order to access the methods

Answer (score 0):

You implement it so that it has an identical signature to that of the interface; so it has to be named `Add`, it has to take a single parameter of type `Num`, and it has to return a single value of type `Num`. Note that that doesn't mean it can take or return a value of *a type that implements `Num`* - the signatures must be *identical*:

```
func (a Frac64) Add(b Num) Num {
    // Pretend this is implemented
    // It can return anything that implements Num
}
```